# Restore the previous highlighted chars quickly?

Tags: vim

Is there a shortcut (or some other quick way) which could restore previous highlighted items quickly, like the one highlighted by <kbd>/</kbd> when `hlsearch` is on?

EDIT: for previous highlighted word, I mean the word highlighted by previous searches via /. 2 search commands with different words are involved here at least.

Comment: what do you mean `previous`?  have you closed vim? what's your viminfo setting? If you didn't close your vim instance, you can just press `n`.

Comment: @Kent, for previous, I mean the highlight is changed to a new word by using <kbd>/</kbd>, so previous one is not highlighted. I'd like to restore highlight to previous word.

Comment: Side note: if highlighting is what you need and you don't mind using a plugin, perhaps you like the plugin called vim-quickhl (https://github.com/t9md/vim-quickhl).

Answer (score 3):

Vim saves previous searches in the search history. You can recall previous searches by pressing <kbd>↑</kbd> in the search *command-line* (which you enter via <kbd>/</kbd>). This even considers the typed prefix, so with `/foo<Up>`, you'll recall previous searches that started with `foo`.

Alternatively, you can enter the command-line window for searches with `q/`. There, you can use the default Vim commands to navigate, move around, and edit, and finally select an entry to search for via <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: +1. is there some way to get the `q/` list programmatically ?

Comment: @Kent: Yes, with `histget('search', index)`.

Answer (score 2):

gv re-selects the last visual selection

gn selects the next search match

Comment: this doesn't answer OP's question. diff between `gn` and `n` is just switching to visual mode.